# is it possible to integrate apache kafka in android?

Tags: android, apache-kafka

I want to know is it possible to integrate [apache kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) in the android world. I have seen few question on internet and found we can use Rest but its not kafka implementation. if it is possible how to integrate it where can i find the android project which implement the latest version of kafka in android?

Comment: What do you mean by integrate? Are you trying to send data to Kafka from an Android device? Are you trying to run a Kafka broker in Android?

Comment: i am trying to implement kafka producer and consumer both at android end

Comment: There is a Java client library for producing and consuming that ships with Apache Kafka. Do you need something else for your case?

Comment: i need setup of these thing in android gradle. ihave read the documentaion and imported the libs from maven but its not working in android throwing runtime exception

Comment: can you help me with blog/step by step installation of kafka in android?

Comment: This is probably worth a separate question.